# C# Unity Script Won't Work

Tags: c#, variables, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

I am a Newbie to C# and Unity, and I was learning about it from videos and made a script that would constantly log to console a number that doubles itself every log

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour {


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    int Example;
    Example = 1;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    Example = Example * 2;
    Debug.Log(Example);
    }
}
```

I thought logically and since

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
```

Is the start, it would only run once, so I created and set a variable there

```
int Example;
Example = 1;
```

and then used the one that updates every frame

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
```

To double the number

```
Example = Example * 2;
Debug.Log(Example);
```

But when I apply this to an object and click play it says "All compiler errors have to be fixed before you can enter play mode" and in the error log it has 1 Warning and 2 errors:

Warning: Assets/Example.cs(9,13): warning CS0219: The variable `Example' is assigned but its value is never used

Error: Assets/Example.cs(15,19): error CS0119: Expression denotes a `type', where a`variable', `value' or`method group' was expected

Error: Assets/Example.cs(16,19): error CS0119: Expression denotes a `type', where a`variable', `value' or`method group' was expected

I feel like this has something to do with the system not recognising "Example"
as a variable that exists, which I don't get since I already defined it before

This is probably a very nooby mistake, but I still have to learn from my mistakes.

Comment: You should probably learn C# before trying to script it.  You're making an extremely basic error caused by not understanding how variable scope works.  And creating a variable with the same name as its containing type... that either won't compile or ugh.  Do yourself a fav, grab CLR Via C#, skip the first two chapters, and read.  It goes by quick.

Comment: You're making a couple errors here. As @Will suggests, you should learn the basics of C# before diving into scripting much more. It won't take you long to get through some basics, so don't fret. Remain persistent, and just understand that if you ever want to make something meaningful beyond tutorials, you're going to need that basic knowledge first. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my guess is that your variable `Example` is not in the correct scope, so your update method does not know it exists. try this:

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour {

 int example; //We declare it outside of the method so it is in the correct scope
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
example = 1;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
example = example * 2;
Debug.Log(example);
}
}
```

edit: as @Jon points out, your variable name is the same as your class name, which is confusing for the compiler. Use a different name. For this example I just made it lowercase `example`

Answer (score 1):

You need to hit up some basic `C#` books and investigate variable scope.
Also `C#` cares about case and so you are calling your int the same thing as the class and the compiler does not know what to do in that case.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour {
    public int example;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {        
        example = 1;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        example = example * 2;
        Debug.Log(example);
    }
}
```

The Unity web page has a lot of tutorials, they go quite fast, but pause and rewind and code along with them should help you.
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you have a variable with the same name as your Class.  Change "int Example" to something else.

Comment: You're missing the scope problem.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't fully analyze the code.  There is also a scope issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some tips (look at commented lines)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour { // <---- Class name is capitalized so dont use same capitalization for "example" inside of class

    int example;  // <----- Put example here so it exists throughout the whole class

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        example = 1; // <---- initialization
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Debug.Log(example *= 2); // <------- Code shortening FTW
    }
}
```

Comment: If code shortening does not increase clarity of intent then it is far from the win.

Answer (score -1):

Your "Example" member is out of scope. And as Will pointed out, the member is the same name as your class.
See below

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour {

    int myExample;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        myExample = 1;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        myExample = myExample * 2;
        Debug.Log(myExample);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't name a variable the same as its containing type.  Brah.